# Double byte character cannot be displayed in figure label

Tags: data-science-experience

I use double byte name in data frame and used data.plot method.
But double byte name cannot be displayed in figure label.
(Showed in a red box of attached picture)
What shall I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoRGf.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by adding some fonts in the fonts directory. 
I just asked how we can add the fonts to the directory of python.
Appearently there is no fonts for Japanese as:

```
!ls /usr/local/src/conda3_runtime.v19/4.1.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf
```

returns:

```
cmb10.ttf  RELEASENOTES.TXT       STIXSizFourSymBol.ttf VeraIt.ttf
cmex10.ttf STIXGeneralBolIta.ttf  STIXSizFourSymReg.ttf VeraMoBd.ttf
cmmi10.ttf STIXGeneralBol.ttf     STIXSizOneSymBol.ttf  VeraMoBI.ttf
cmr10.ttf  STIXGeneralItalic.ttf  STIXSizOneSymReg.ttf  VeraMoIt.ttf
cmss10.ttf STIXGeneral.ttf        STIXSizThreeSymBol.ttf VeraMono.ttf
cmsy10.ttf STIXNonUniBolIta.ttf   STIXSizThreeSymReg.ttf VeraSeBd.ttf
cmtt10.ttf STIXNonUniBol.ttf      STIXSizTwoSymBol.ttf   VeraSe.ttf
COPYRIGHT.TXT  STIXNonUniIta.ttf  STIXSizTwoSymReg.ttf  Vera.ttf
LICENSE_STIX   STIXNonUni.ttf         VeraBd.ttf
README.TXT     STIXSizFiveSymReg.ttf  VeraBI.ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do it.
Installation steps are as follow:

```
!wget http://ipafont.ipa.go.jp/old/ipaexfont/ipaexg00201.php
!mv ipaexg00201.php ipaexg00201.zip
!unzip ipaexg00201.zip
!cp ipaexg00201/ipaexg.ttf $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/
!cp $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-    data/matplotlibrc $HOME/.config/matplotlib/
!echo 'font.family : IPAexGothic' >>   $HOME/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
!rm -r $HOME/.cache/matplotlib/*
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel(u'豆腐 - tofu')
plt.title(u'豆腐 - TOFU')
```